# cmake give undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, bluez

Hi I'm trying to use `bluez` source code to control some stuff in my code.

In my cmake I first start doing instruction like

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/attrib/)
```

then

```
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../bluez/attrib/ SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST)
```

and finaly add `SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST` to my `add_executable`

But I still have

```
undefined reference to gatt_connect(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, int, int, void (*)(_GIOChannel*, _GError*, void*), _GError**)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the content of `SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST` (`MESSAGE(${SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST})`)?

Comment: path to sources files from the attrib folder in bluez source

Comment: And they define `gatt_connect` symbol?

Comment: yes it's defined in utils.c wich is showed in results of MESSAGE(${SRC_BLUEZ_ATTRIB_LIST})

Comment: In which header is it declared? Your source code is `c++`?

Comment: it's declared in gatttool.h
and yes i'm using c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [extern "C"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/2838364) in your `c++` source file

```
extern "C" {
   #include "gatttool.h"
}
```